# Is it possible to connect Google App engine Flexi with Cloud Nat

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, reverse-proxy, nat

Since GAE doesn't provide static IP's,Is there is any way to connect Cloud NAT for all the egress connection from Google App Engine.

Switching Platform from GAE to Compute Engine or Running proxy in Compute Engine is not in the scope.

Comment: Cloud NAT is for systems running in a VPC. App Engine does not run in a VPC. Therefore, if you want to use Cloud NAT with App Engine (have a public IP address for outgoing requests), you will need to launch a GCE instance in a VPC, set up Cloud NAT and then tunnel your App Engine traffic thru that GCE instance. With that setup, you do not need NAT if you assign the GCE instance a public IP address. Setting up an SSH or HTTP tunnel is easy and there are many libraries to do this. Google Search.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks for the answer, but i have already mentioned the suggestion which you had said, in my question. I was looking for some other tweaks .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Cloud NAT (network address translation)](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/overview)** is primarely designed for **Google Cloud Platform (GCP) virtual machine (VM) instances without external IP addresses** and **private Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) clusters** to connect to **the Internet**.

---

> **You are correct, App Engine does not currently provide a way to map static IP addresses to an application. Instead, Google App Engine hosts your service on a dynamic public IP address of a Google load balancer.**

If you are trying to use Cloud NAT with your Google App Engine Flexible Environment. I would suggest you **set up a Google Compute Engine VM to be used as a proxy for your Google App Engine application**, as suggested in this **[Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47745439/using-google-compute-engine-as-a-proxy-for-a-google-app-engine-web-app)**.

---

As the **[Official Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/#static-ip)** suggests, note that using static IP address filtering is not considered a safe and effective means of protection. For example, an attacker could set up a malicious App Engine app which could share the same IP address range as your application. Instead, we suggest that you take a defense in depth approach using OAuth and Certs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i have already mentioned the suggestion which you had said, in my question. I was looking for some other tweaks

Comment: Hi @Tibin, my answer is based on the documentation, as I am not aware of any other alternative methods.